# Jenkins Environment Dashboard plug-in NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: jenkins

I've been using the Environment Dashboard plug-in for quite a while now... I believe someone updated other plug-ins or changed the configuration, or even accidentally deleted the h2 DB. Ever since then I can't get the environment dashboard to work.

When I try creating a new dashboard, I get:

`javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jenkinsci.plugins.environmentdashboard.EnvDashboardView`

I tried removing and re-adding the plug-in a few times, including manually. I also tried extracting `classes.jar` but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Any luck with that?

Comment: Nope :( I saw your comment on the developers list - let's keep waiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solved it here a couple of hours ago.

1. Delete (backup it up before) the following environment dashboard files from JENKINS_HOME: jenkins_dashboard.mv.db  jenkins_dashboard.trace.db  jenkins_dashboard.trace.db.old  org.jenkinsci.plugins.environmentdashboard.DashboardBuilder.xml.
2. Re-install the plugin.

Hope it works for you as well.